# Application force closes when logging in to facebook with Facebook Unity SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

I have created a simple button to test Facebook login with Facebook Unity SDK in my game. The login works perfectly within the Unity editor but the application force closes when testing on my HTC explorer. Also tested the game on BlueStacks and it crashes there also when trying to log in.

When building the game in unity, at the end I get the following error:

> Your Android setup is not correct. See Settings in Facebook menu. `UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()`

I am using the Facebook Unity SDK 5.0.3 and Unity 4.3.0

I also tried changing the android manifest as suggested [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/note-for-android)

I've also created the keyhash with openssl and pasted that on the Facebook app settings page as unity does not show the key hash value in the "Android Build Facebook Settings" in the inspector.

I am new to unity and am stuck with this for a long time now. Please someone help.

---

#### Below is the logcat:

---

```
03-25 22:03:09.726: D/dalvikvm(7014): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1809K, 32% free 8385K/12295K, external 0K/0K, paused 54ms+111ms
03-25 22:03:09.766: D/FBUnitySDK(7077): KeyHash: TC01uDQHTkrLbLaTLSfdTA/bEuI=
03-25 22:03:09.766: D/AndroidRuntime(7077): Shutting down VM
03-25 22:03:09.766: W/dalvikvm(7077): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4020b5a0)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): Unity version     : 4.3.0f4
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): Device model      : HTC HTC Explorer A310e
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): Device fingerprint: htc_asia_india/htc_pico/pico:2.3.5/GRJ90/214721.3:user/release-keys
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction(Session.java:1328)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at com.facebook.Session.setActiveSession(Session.java:790)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at com.facebook.unity.FB.initAndLogin(FB.java:86)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at com.facebook.unity.FB.LoginUsingActivity(FB.java:249)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity.onCreate(FBUnityLoginActivity.java:13)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 22:03:09.776: E/EmbeddedLogger(176): App crashed! Process: com.jalanubha.Progamer
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176): App crashed! Package: com.jalanubha.Progamer v1 (1.0)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176): Error getting package label: com.jalanubha.Progamer
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at com.htc.server.embedded.EmbeddedLogger.onHandleApplicationCrash(EmbeddedLogger.java:59)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerService.java:7739)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1033)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1657)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1083)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 22:03:09.786: E/EmbeddedLogger(176): Application Label: <ERROR>
03-25 22:03:09.786: W/ActivityManager(176):   Force finishing activity com.jalanubha.Progamer/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity
03-25 22:03:09.786: W/ActivityManager(176):   Force finishing activity com.jalanubha.Progamer/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity
03-25 22:03:09.846: D/WindowManagerImpl(176): addView, new view, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40c36d00
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): Exception during service
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): java.net.UnknownHostException: graph.facebook.com
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:512)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:300)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:259)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(FbHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:133)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:160)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:148)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientRequestExecutor.a(FbHttpClientRequestExecutor.java:60)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.executors.qebased.QeHttpRequestExecutor.a(QeHttpRequestExecutor.java:61)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.RequestFlowStateController.a(RequestFlowStateController.java:89)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.FbRedirectController.a(FbRedirectController.java:93)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:173)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:148)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:103)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:241)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:402)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:164)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:26)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiMethodRunnerImpl.a(ApiMethodRunnerImpl.java:43)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiMethodRunnerImpl.a(ApiMethodRunnerImpl.java:35)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.orca.protocol.WebServiceHandler.b(WebServiceHandler.java:174)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:31)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.orca.database.DbServiceHandler.b(DbServiceHandler.java:259)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:31)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.orca.cache.CacheServiceHandler.b(CacheServiceHandler.java:138)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:31)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:302)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:54)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:232)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-25 22:03:10.147: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7014): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
03-25 22:03:10.287: W/ActivityManager(176): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40b04798 com.jalanubha.Progamer/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Order and Export in project properties make sure that you have checked the Android Private Libraries checkbox